# message passing in chrome extension programing

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Can contenscript.js communicate with option.js using

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest()
```

and

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener()
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, that's the point. See http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html

Here's an example if you need one :

Sending :

https://github.com/Canop/Chrall/blob/master/chrome/chrall/chrall_cdm.js

Receiving :

https://github.com/Canop/Chrall/blob/master/chrome/chrall/chrome-extension.html

Comment: then why i am getting undefined in line 2 of
`1. chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "getStatus"}, function(response) {
2.  console.log(response.status);});`
although i have defined
`chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener()` in 
option.js

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

*In the content script:*

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "getStatus"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.status);
});
```

*In the extension script:*

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.method === "getStatus") sendResponse({status: "status"});
});
```

Comment: Ok thats fine but how can i pass **whole local storage** to **contentscript** as a response ??

Comment: you can't. But you can access local storage directly in contentscript.

Comment: We he can't? Local storage is just a plain JSON. Simply send `{localStorage: JSON.stringify(localStorage)}`.